# Adding event listeners to buttons created from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mouseevent, createelement

I'm creating buttons out of "tags" taken from my database. I'd like to add mouse event listeners to each button. However, the listener only seems to work on the last created button. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var tagsContainer = document.getElementById('tags');
var tagarray = placetags.split(" ");
for (var tagcounter = 0; tagcounter < tagarray.length; tagcounter++){
  var tag = document.createElement('input');
  tag.type = 'button';
  tag.value = tagarray[tagcounter];
  tag.id = 'tagbutton';
  tagsContainer.appendChild(tag);
  tag.addEventListener('mouseover' , function(){
    tag.style.color = 'white';
  });
  tag.addEventListener('mouseout' , function(){
    tag.style.color = 'orange';
  });
}
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mjqWL/3/

Comment: thanks.  a simple "this.style.color" instead of "tag.style.color"  of course!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even realize that I changed that. Adam's answer explains why.

Comment: @Blender - a badge for your troubles :)

Comment: Note that you can use a [single event handler](http://jsfiddle.net/mjqWL/4/) for all of your buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your handlers from this

```
tag.addEventListener('mouseover' , function(){
    tag.style.color = 'white';
});
```

to this

```
tag.addEventListener('mouseover' , function(){
    this.style.color = 'white';
});
```

Since with your original code, your handlers are *closing over* the tag variable, and so `tag` ends up referring to the last button created.

Comment: I'm still seeing multiple buttons, however.  Right now I'm just looking to do mouseover / mouseout events.